# nmap OS scan showing DD-WRT when I'm not running it?

Tags: nmap, network-scanners, firmware

This weekend, I set up pfSense on a spare box that I had sitting in the garage. It seems cool and powerful, but I haven't messed with it much yet.

Was doing some basic nmap scanning from work against my home public IP, and the nmap scan is apparently saying I'm running DD-WRT? My only other router (wireless) is sitting behind the pfSense box and it is running stock firmware, not DD-WRT. Can anyone help to explain this output? Perhaps it's just an erroneous guess as the output suggests it may not be accurate? Thank you.

```
root@kali:~# nmap -O my public IP

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-02 11:03 EST
Nmap scan report for my public IP
Host is up (0.015s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6668/tcp closed irc
6669/tcp closed irc
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: general purpose
Running: Linux 2.4.X|3.X
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3
OS details: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (Linux 2.4.37), Linux 3.2

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 50.44 seconds
```

Comment: FWIW: I have a stock EA3500 and EA6500. Both have the latest firmware, and I'm reasonably confident in their integrity. The 3500 shows up as DD-WRT v24 SP1. The 6500 comes back as Linux 2.6.22 (embedded, ARM). Both results claim 100% accuracy, though the scan on the 3500 had a warning that OS Detection didn't resolve on the first try. It's probably a safe bet that DD-WRT is just sufficiently similar to stock firmware that Nmap sometimes can't tell the difference.

Comment: You mention this is at home.  What are you using for your modem?  DSL, Cable, etc?  I'd expect the OS fingerprinting to identify the modem, not what's behind the modem.

Comment: For reference, Nmap against my routers was executed with the following options: `nmap -sV -p - -O -v --version-all` and there is one hop (the EA6500) between me and the router that's showing up as DD-WRT.

Comment: That's a great point, @Iszi. Also Steve, I would agree that the OS detection would probably be the main point of egress, or the modem.

Comment: @SteveSether That's a big, huge, "it depends" based upon his network configuration. For all intents and purposes, a modem should be fairly transparent to Nmap. Even a full-blown "home gateway" device (integrated modem, router, sometimes Wireless AP and other stuff) could be configured in such a way that Nmap would return an ID for a system behind it (e.g. "DMZ Host") rather than the gateway itself.

Comment: @Iszi I've seen many home setups over the years in multiple different countries, and they're almost always serving up private NAT to the internal network.  With no open ports the OS detection is going to use packets returned by the first device it hits, which is most likely the modem.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is in your question :

```
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
```

Nmap literally guesses which OS is on the machine. Didn't work out this time.

Comment: And there's also a note where to report to improve detection.

Comment: Understood, and I read that. Needed some confirmation from some folks who may be much better versed with nmap than myself. Thanks guys.

Comment: Our pleasure !!

Comment: @FrancoisRenaud-Philippon The answer here is *probably* correct for this case. But what if we put on our tinfoil hats and ask "How can I tell that my router hasn't actually been hacked, and had a DD-WRT derivative put on that just has a stock-looking UI?".

Comment: ^^^ This is a great way to look at it.